# How to check whether any WooCommerce order contains a product-ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm coding a plugin which should check whether an order contains an product-ID.

How can I check all orders if any contains the product-ID and then mark this order as finished?

I know how to check an order on thankyou-page, but the order-ID there is already given:

Thank you all and @johnnyd23 for the code below.

```php
foreach ( $order_summary as $order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order->order_id );
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $items = $order->get_items();

    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            if ( $product_id == XYZ ) {
                 // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time grasping why you are using a foreach loop where `foreach ($array as $value)` directly followed by `$value = 'some other value'`. While it may still work, I would recommend using something other than `$order` as the predominate variable in the loop, as it would typically be the placeholder for an index in the `$order_summary` array. It may work, but it makes my head hurt

Comment: Your question context is not clear and the provided code is not testable. Remember that *"questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"*.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is check if this order id is what you need and update order status

```
 if($order_id == 'Your_required_id'){
   $order->update_status( 'completed' );
 }
```

You could change your code something as the following

```
foreach ( $order_summary as $order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order->order_id );
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {
      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_id == XYZ ) {
         // do something
          $order->update_status( 'completed' );
      }
     }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it. Tailor the code according to your needs

Comment: Please describe the reason for downvote as it will help to understand my mistake